# In Objective C where the predefined classes are stored?

Tags: c, objective-c

In C if we include #stdio.h we get some functions like printf, scanf. In the same way for Objective C what we should do to include NSLog,NSArray,... and where the definitions of these NSLog, NSArray are stored ? Please clarify my confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding to what jib wrote: to use those functions, one puts a line

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

at the top of the source code. This corresponds to `#include <stdio.h>` in the standard C.
In OS X,

```
#import <FirstPart/SecondPart.h>
```

reads the header file at `FirstPart.framework` somewhere in the framework search path (typically, `/System/Library/Frameworks`) and then the `SecondPart.h` is looked up inside `FirstPart.framework/Headers/`. So, in the case of `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>`, the file is at `/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h`. Now, if you open that file, you see it just have lots of other `#import`'s, as in :

```
#import <Foundation/NSObjCRuntime.h>
#import <Foundation/NSArray.h>
#import <Foundation/NSAutoreleasePool.h>
....
```

and the real definitions are in those files. In general, you shouldn't import those individual headers, but should just import the main header (in this case `Foundation/Foundation.h`); the compiler has an optimization which makes it faster that way.

Comment: All Header files are there. But where will be the implementation (.m) files stored.

Comment: .m files are not public. Only the compiled library is shipped with the OS. The compiled libraries are called `Foo.framework/Foo`.

Answer (score 3):

NSLog and NSArray are both defined in Foundation.framework. In XCode cmd-click on a symbol to jump to a definition. You can add the enviroment variable DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES  to your app to log Library loads on app launch.

Answer (score 0):

NSLog, NSArray and other basic classes are included in Framework.h file. To import all these classes in your program simply add

`#import Framework\Framework.h`
and leave rest for the compiler.